# How to optimize a sequence of as-operations with null checks?

Tags: c#, optimization, casting, type-conversion

I would like to optimize the following sequence, because the runtime has linear growth, the more as-Operations I add. Is there a smarter way to implement this in the same class without using further helper classes / patterns? 
Thanks in advance (and sorry about the edits..)!

```
public void SomeMethod(ClassZero foo)
{
    var targetName = "";

    var a = foo as ClassA;
    if (a != null) targetName = a.DoSomething();

    var b = foo as ClassB;
    if (b != null) targetName = b.DoSomethingElse();

    var c = foo as ClassC;
    if (c != null) targetName = c.DoSomethingEntirelyElse();

    var d = foo as ClassD;
    if (c != null) targetName = d.DoSomethingInAnotherParallelWorld();

    var furtherUse = localVariable.Process(targetName);
}
```

Comment: Would highly encourage that you look into whether or not you can use an abstract base class or interface for the instead. Also, I'd assume you could probably `return` if you find a match, which your code does not do. That'd prevent any extraneous type checks. Aside from that, if you need to check the type then you're going to have to spend the time to do it. I'd be doubtful you'll find a performance bottleneck in your type checking here.

Comment: I would reconsider my design, you could simply work on an interface in this place and inject a concrete implementation of the method you are calling right here. Basically ClassA and ClassB implement IDoWork, which contains a void DoWork() method. And you simply call it directly in the abovecode

Comment: `without using further helper classes / patterns?`  When you code needs to be improved you're very likely going to want to use a helper class/pattern of some sort to accomplish that.  You're essentially prohibiting the best solutions to your problem any time you provide such a constraint to yourself.  When faced with problems like this what you should be asking is how can I leverage a helper class or a patter to encapsulate a mechanic/behavior of my program.

Comment: Do you actually expect to have so many classes here that linearly checking them is actually going to be a performance problem?   You'd probably need to have tens, if not hundreds of *thousands* of different classes for that to be the case, and if you have that many classes here than you'll have much more than just performance problems.  This code is going to become unmaintainable *long* before it would ever be a performance problem.

Comment: @Dominik yeach, didnt read question clearly, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, instead of interrogating the base class for the type and picking a different public method, you would have a single method call on the base class (or, even better, an interface) that can be called regardless of the underlying implementation.

In general, this is called Polymorphism, wherein you can treat multiple derived classes the same when interacting them as their base class.

```
public void SomeMethod(ClassZero foo)
{
    var targetName = "";

    targetName = foo.GetTargetName();

    var furtherUse = localVariable.Process(targetName);
}
```

And elsewhere:

```
public abstract class ClassZero
{
    public abstract string GetTargetName();
}

public class ClassA : ClassZero
{
    public override string GetTargetName()
    { 
        return DoSomething();
    }
}

public class ClassB : ClassZero
{
    public override string GetTargetName()
    { 
        return DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use an interface. This would often be preferred, since it's an explicit contract about a class that it provides a function to, in this case, get a TargetName. It's a little less obfuscated vs. having an abstract method on an abstract base class. It's also good if you don't own the ClassZero base class.

```
public interface ITargetNameGenerator
{
    string GetTargetName();
}

public void SomeMethod(ITargetNameGenerator foo)
{
    var targetName = "";

    targetName = foo.GetTargetName();

    var furtherUse = localVariable.Process(targetName);
}


public class ClassA : ClassZero, ITargetNameGenerator
{
    public string GetTargetName()
    {
        return DoSomething();
    }
}
//etc...
```

Comment: I definitely agree that this is the correct solution, but it might be helpful to show how to implement this with interfaces in case they don't have ownership of ClassZero. Something like public ClassA : ClassZero, IGetTargetNames etc.